# Python shows no error code, but has no output

Tags: python

I am brand new to coding so I hope this is a small mistake. Below is the code for an assignment on a paper carrier's salary. I get no error codes but no output, even the print functions do not show. Please help

```py
# This program will calculate the weekly pay of a paper carrier.

# Developer: Hannah Ploeger Date: 08/30/2022

def main():
    # initialize variables
    paperCost = 4
    commission = 0.05

    # prompt user for number of papers
    numPaper = eval(input("How many papers are delivered on your route?"))

    # prompt user for days of delivery
    numDays = eval(input("How many days was the paper delivered this week"))

    # prompt user for tips recieved
    numTips = input("How much did you recieve in tips this week?")

    # calculate salary
    weekPay = ((numPaper * numDays) * paperCost) * commission
    totalPay = weekPay + numTips

    # display output
    print("This week you delivered", numPaper, "papers")
    print("Your salary this week is $", weekPay)
    print("Your total tips were $", numTips)
    print("Your total pay is $", totalPay)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3E6K.png)

Comment: You've put all your code in the body of the `main` function, but you aren't actually calling/invoking/triggering the `main` function anywhere, so your code effectively does nothing.

Comment: Do you actually call `main` at some point?

Comment: Also, you should do `eval` on `numTips` too

Comment: If you expect the input to be a number, you should call `float(...)` or `int(...)` on the inuput instead of `eval(...)` this way if the user types an incorrect value, a more specific error will be displayed. (And it's good practice security-wise to be in the habit of limiting user input to exactly what you expect it ought to be, and to reject the input if it doesn't fit.)

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

just call the main function

```
def main():
   # initialize variables
   paperCost = 4
   commission = 0.05

   # prompt user for number of papers
   numPaper = eval(input("How many papers are delivered on your route?"))

   # prompt user for days of delivery
   numDays = eval(input("How many days was the paper delivered this week"))

   # prompt user for tips recieved
   numTips = input("How much did you recieve in tips this week?")

   # calculate salary
   weekPay = ((numPaper * numDays) * paperCost) * commission
   totalPay = weekPay + numTips

   # display output
   print("This week you delivered", numPaper, "papers")
   print("Your salary this week is $", weekPay)
   print("Your total tips were $", numTips)
   print("Your total pay is $", totalPay)

main() # calling main function
```